# Cytoscape and react- cytoscape.js-expand-collapse error

Tags: reactjs, cytoscape.js

Hi I am using react cytoscape with COSBilkent layout, I also imported cytoscape-expand-collapse. When I click on Icon for collapsing I receive error: Uncaught TypeError: cy.undoRedo is not a function. Does anyone knows why, below is my code:

```
import COSEBilkent from 'cytoscape-cose-bilkent';
import React, { useRef, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import CytoscapeComponent from 'react-cytoscapejs';
import expandCollapse from 'cytoscape-expand-collapse';

import elements from './data';

expandCollapse(Cytoscape);
Cytoscape.use(COSEBilkent);

const Test = ({}) => {
  const [cy, setCy] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (cy) {
      cy.expandCollapse();
    }
  });
  const layout = { name: 'cose-bilkent' };

  return (
    <CytoscapeComponent
      cy={cy => {
        setCy(cy);
      }}
      layout={layout}
      elements={elements}
      style={{ width: '600px', height: '600px' }}
    />
  );
};

export default Test;
```

Comment: Have you tried to import undo/redo? The expand-collapse extension sometimes uses the Undo/Redo functionality, even in one of the (vanilla cytoscape.js) [examples] (https://github.com/iVis-at-Bilkent/cytoscape.js-expand-collapse/blob/master/demo-undoable.html). I would suggest you to change the import order just to minimize the possible errors.

Comment: Ok I imorted, it turned out tht there are 2 versions of undo-redo;/ Could you please tell me what do you mean by 'I would suggest you to change the import order just to minimize the possible errors.'??

Comment: The link I provided shows you the demo.html for the expand-collapse extension. You can import your dependencies (cytoscape-react, cose-bilkent, expand-collapse and so on) in the order the demo.html imports them in the head. First cytoscape, then cose-bilkent, then undo-redo and lastly expand-collapse